# WordPress Framework

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, для чего нужны фреймворки для WordPress такие, например, как Redux или Unison? Если я, к примеру, занимаюсь разработкой тем не для Themeforest, а просто делаю посадку готовой вёрстки на WP? В чем удобство?

Comment: Ты точно хочешь узнать "в чем удобство" или "как правильнее делать"?

Comment: Ну я так понимаю, что удобства в этом нету ? просто так делать правильнее ?)

Comment: Нет. ТАК - НЕ правильнее. Но допустимо.

Comment: можешь тогда сказать, как правильнее ? Или дай ссылку где почитать можно, спасибо

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос философский, общего плана и подлежит закрытию, поскольку "порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях" (из правил сообщества).

Как любая дополнительная подсистема, будь то плагин или "красивая" тема, framework создаёт дополнительную нагрузку на WordPress. Но взамен иногда существенно ускоряет разработку - например, когда вам нужно сделать массу опций на странице настройки темы, а эти опции ещё и требуют изощрённой валидации.

Решать вам - что для вас важнее: выигрыш во времени разработки или проигрыш в быстродействии сайта.